# Dataframe pivot without sorting the column names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Original data :-

```
date   variable    value
2017    A             1
2017    C             1
2017    B             2
2018    A             1
2018    C             1
2018    B             2
```

My pivot Result :-

```
date   A        B        C
2017   1        2        1
2018   1        2        1
```

Expected Output :-

```
date   A     C     B
2017   1     1     2
2018   1     1     2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this with [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Categorical.html):

```
df.variable=pd.Categorical(df.variable,categories=df.variable.unique(),ordered=True)
df.pivot_table(index='date',columns='variable',values='value')
```

---

```
variable  A  C  B
date             
2017      1  1  2
2018      1  1  2
```

This sets the order as `df.variable.unique()` which is `[A, C, B]`

Answer (score 0):

The following command (from [how can i unstack without sorting in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48636363/how-can-i-unstack-without-sorting-in-pandas)) is ok for me :

```py
print(df.unstack(0).reindex(pd.unique(df.index.get_level_values(1))).sort_index(axis=1,level=1).T)
```

and returns :

```
      A  C  B
2017  1  1  2
2018  1  1  2
```