# Stop Pandas from sorting columns

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, columnsorting

I am trying to produce a report and then I run the below code

```
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_excel("proposals2020.xlsx", sheet_name="Proposals")

    country_probability = df.groupby(["Country", "Probability"]).count()
    country_probability = country_probability.unstack()
    country_probability = country_probability.fillna("0")
    country_probability = country_probability.drop(country_probability.columns[4:], axis=1)
    country_probability = country_probability.drop(country_probability.columns[0], axis=1)
    country_probability = country_probability.astype(int)

    print(country_probability)
```

I get the below results:

```
             Quote Number           
Probability          High Low Medium
Country                             
Algeria                 3   1      9
Bahrain                 4   3      2
Egypt                   2   0      3
Iraq                    3   0      8
Jordan                  0   1      1
Lebanon                 0   1      0
Libya                   1   0      0
Morocco                 0   0      2
Pakistan                3  10     11
Qatar                   0   1      1
Saudi Arabia           16   8     19
Tunisia                 2   5      0
USA                     0   1      0
```

My question is how to stop pandas from sorting these columns alphabetically and keep the High, Medium, Low order...

Comment: Is it something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48636363/how-can-i-unstack-without-sorting-in-pandas

Comment: Try df.sort_values(['High', 'Medium', 'Low'])

Comment: Groupby has a variable sort which is by default set to True, you can pass sort = False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

```
# if isinstance(df.columns, pd.MultiIndex)
df = df.reindex(['High', 'Medium', 'Low'], axis=1, level=1)
```

If not MultiIndex in columns:

```
# if isinstance(df.columns, pd.Index)
df = df.reindex(['High', 'Medium', 'Low'], axis=1)
```

We can also try pass **sort = False** in `groupby`:

```
country_probability = df.groupby(["Country", "Probability"], sort=False).count()
```