# Is it even possible to reshape this using Pandas?

Tags: pandas, pivot, pandas-melt

I have this dataframe (with all 50 states and more categories, but if we can get this to work, I can apply it to the whole dataset):

```
                   US     US_bp   US_bp%       AL   AL_bp  AL_bp%
total_pop   324173084  41393176     12.8  4920613  794326    16.1
white       198511109  19510415      9.8  3218517  378269    11.8
black        38526055   8402643     21.8  1260356  327284    26.0
```

And need this:

```
    place  total_pop        bp    bp%  white_pop  white_bp  white_bp%  black_pop  black_bp  black_bp%
0      US  324173084  41393176   12.8  198511109  19510415        9.8    8402643    840263       21.4
1      AL    4920613    794326   16.1    3218517    378269       11.8    1260356    327284       26.0
```

How can I do this with Pandas? I tried melt and pivot, but can't wrap my head around what might work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Writing a more specific title might help get more eyes on this. Check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a partial solution: Convert the columns into a MultiIndex, then stack and unstack.

I'm using a regex for the first step: Extract two uppercase characters optionally followed by an underscore plus the other part.

```
col_pairs = df.columns.str.extract(r'^([A-Z]{2})(?:_(.*))?$').fillna('pop')
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(col_pairs.T.values)

(df
    .stack(level=0)
    .unstack(level=0)
    .swaplevel(axis=1)
    # Fix order
    .reindex(df.index, axis=1, level=0)
    .reindex(df.columns.get_level_values(1).unique(), axis=1, level=1)
    .reindex(df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique())
    )
```

```
   total_pop                      white                     black               
         pop        bp   bp%        pop        bp   bp%       pop       bp   bp%
US 324173084  41393176  12.8  198511109  19510415   9.8  38526055  8402643  21.8
AL   4920613    794326  16.1    3218517    378269  11.8   1260356   327284  26.0
```

I'd prefer if stacking/unstacking didn't sort, but at least [you can fix that by reindexing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48636483/4518341). I'm also not bothering to get the labels *exactly* as you want them, but most of that's easy.

*Due credit to sammywemmy for [the stack/unstack technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76708707/4518341).*

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html#pandas-wide-to-long):

```py
stubnames = sorted(set(c.split('_')[0] for c in df.columns))
df.columns = (c if '_' in c else c + '_total_pop' for c in df.columns)
df = df.rename(index={'total_pop': ''})

df = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames, i='index', j='xxx', sep='_', suffix=r'.*').T
df.columns = (f'{a}_{b}'.strip('_') for a, b in df.columns)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      total_pop  white_total_pop  black_total_pop          bp    white_bp   black_bp   bp%  white_bp%  black_bp%
AL    4920613.0        3218517.0        1260356.0    794326.0    378269.0   327284.0  16.1       11.8       26.0
US  324173084.0      198511109.0       38526055.0  41393176.0  19510415.0  8402643.0  12.8        9.8       21.8
```

Answer (score 1):

- rename the columns to cater for those that dont have an ending with `_`:

```py
df.columns = [f"{col}_pop" if "bp" not in col else col for col in df]
```

- create a MultiIndex from the columns:

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.split("_", expand=True)
```

- reshape the dataframe with a combination of stack, unstack, swaplevel:

```py
df = df.stack(level=0).unstack(level=0).swaplevel(axis=1)
```

- run a list comprehension to build the final column to your expected output:

```py
df.columns = [first if last in first 
              else last if first == "total_pop" 
              else f"{first}_{last}" 
              for first, last in df]

df.index.name = 'place'

       black_bp        bp  white_bp  black_bp%   bp%  white_bp%  black_pop  total_pop  white_pop
place                                                                                           
AL       327284    794326    378269       26.0  16.1       11.8    1260356    4920613    3218517
US      8402643  41393176  19510415       21.8  12.8        9.8   38526055  324173084  198511109
```

Comment: You can add `.sort_index(axis=1, level=0)` after `swaplevel` to get the order closer to what OP wants