# Pandas Multi-index on 2 Levels

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a json which is in the following format :

```
data = {
    'Low': {
        '2023.07.01': {"u": "mo", 'N': 1, 'O': 2, "PN": 22, "PO": 34},
        '2023.07.02': {"u": "no", 'N': 1, 'O': 2, "PN": 22, "PO": 34}
    },
    'Medium': {
        '2023.07.01': {"u": "no", 'N': 1, 'O': 2, "PN": 22, "PO": 34},
        '2023.07.02': {"u": "mo", 'N': 1, 'O': 2, "PN": 22, "PO": 34}
    },
    'High': {
        '2023.07.01': {"u": "no", 'N': 122, 'O': 2, "PN": 212, "PO": 334},
        '2023.07.02': {"u": "mo", 'N': 13, 'O': 2, "PN": 2, "PO": 342}
    }
}
```

How can i create a multi level dataframe with the following structure :

```
            Low              Medium            High         
            N   PN  O   PN   N  PN  O   PN     N    PN  O   PN
Date    U
```

I have tried various ways like `df.stack` and `df.pivot` but I was not able to get the exact format I needed.

Comment: "I have tried..." - please post the code you tried, and what did/didn't work, as you expected it?

Comment: What happened to `PO`? mistyped as `PN`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
(df.stack().apply(pd.Series)
   .set_index('u',append=True)
   .stack().unstack(level=(1,-1))
)
```

Output:

```
               Low                  Medium                    High                   
                 N    O    PN    PO      N    O    PN    PO      N    O     PN     PO
           u                                                                         
2023.07.01 mo  1.0  2.0  22.0  34.0    NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
           no  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    1.0  2.0  22.0  34.0  122.0  2.0  212.0  334.0
2023.07.02 mo  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    1.0  2.0  22.0  34.0   13.0  2.0    2.0  342.0
           no  1.0  2.0  22.0  34.0    NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Just in case this is not obvious to OP: `df = pd.DataFrame(data)` ;)

Comment: Thanks! Quang Hoang, and also mozway, that was really not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

What I might do is convert the data to long format first (i.e. one data point per row) outside of Pandas, then unstack.

I've also added names to the column labels to make it easier to work with them, but the names themselves are just a guess: "rank" and "measure".

```
long = {}
for rank, d0 in data.items():
    for date, d1 in d0.items():
        d1_copy = d1.copy()
        u = d1_copy.pop('u')
        for measure, v in d1_copy.items():
            long[(date, u, rank, measure)] = v

s = pd.Series(long).rename_axis(['Date', 'u', 'rank', 'measure'])
df = s.unstack(['rank', 'measure'])
df
```

```
rank           Low                  Medium                    High                   
measure          N    O    PN    PO      N    O    PN    PO      N    O     PN     PO
Date       u                                                                         
2023.07.01 mo  1.0  2.0  22.0  34.0    NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
           no  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    1.0  2.0  22.0  34.0  122.0  2.0  212.0  334.0
2023.07.02 mo  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    1.0  2.0  22.0  34.0   13.0  2.0    2.0  342.0
           no  1.0  2.0  22.0  34.0    NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
```

---

If the real data isn't all the same type, you can use this more general approach. It just requires a bit of finagling to get things laid out the same after unstacking.

```
long = {
    (date, rank): d1
    for rank, d0 in data.items()
    for date, d1 in d0.items()}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(long, orient='index').set_index('u', append=True)

(df.unstack(1)
 .swaplevel(axis=1)
 [df.index.get_level_values(1).unique()]  # Unsort
 .rename_axis(index={None: 'Date'}, columns=['rank', 'measure'])
 )
```

- Related: [How can i unstack without sorting in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48636363/4518341)

(same output)